# Derivative and integral for a function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Someone has asked similiar question before, but the answer to that question ***omits the proof***. 
And I couldn't find the proof on Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis or Stein's Real Analysis.

Prove that :$
\int_a^b |f'(x)|\,dx \leq V(f,[a,b])$, where f is a function of bounded variation.

I tried to imitate the proof of  "$ 
\int_a^b |g'(x)|\,dx \ = V(g,[a,b])$, where g is absolutely continuous", but failed.
I also tried to use the Lebsgue decomposition, but I didn't know what to do next.

Any hint will be appreciated!!